# How to increase the size of a link?

Tags: html, hyperlink, fonts

Hi i need to display my link in footer as "powered by Arun" and it should be a link to my homepage. I need to give a different look to the name next to **Powered by**. So how to increase the size of the link and any suggestions for customizing the link well.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `<span>` element:

```
<span>Powered By</span> Arun
```

You can then apply a style to the span, or a class:

- Inline style:

  ```
  <span style="font-size:1.2em;"></span>
  ```
- Class style:

  apply the class:

  ```
  <span class="mySpanClass"></span>
  ```

  and specify corresponding style (in a stylesheet):

  ```
  .mySpanClass { font-size:1.2em; }
  ```

Comment: He needs a link. Also, I guess he wants to style up the word next to powered by i.e. his name 'Arun'

Comment: He may have a link, there's nothing stopping that - and I presume he _has_ that, this is just to slot in between the link tags.

Comment: Yeap, but looking at his question, I am pretty much sure, he wont feel comfortable placing it inside link :)

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need something like this,

```
<a href='linkToHomePage' style='font-size:1.2em'>Powered by<span style="font-weight:bold">Arun</span></a>
```

(I am guessing your are not a technical person, so this will be easy for you)

And if you can do, please do this,

Add this css,

```
.poweredby {
  font-size:1.2em;
}
.author {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

And add this markup,

```
<a href='linkToHomePage' class='poweredby'>Powered by<span class="author">Arun</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As denoted by Mr. Disappointment in his answer you can use a `<span>`.

To show an example of using it with the link, see below.

```
<a href="LinkToYouHomePage.htm"><span style="font-size: small">Powered by</span> <span
    style="font-size: larger">Arun</span> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give some basic style to a link couldn't you do

```
<p><a href="https://iden.example.org"><i style="font-size:1.5em ;color: blue; ">Powered by</i><strong> Arun</strong></a></p>
```